# Qt Save form take 3-4 second to open

Tags: forms, qt, save

i'm using this on push button click in Qt:

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("Save file"),
                                                QString(),
                                                tr("(*.csv));
```

it take 3-4 second to open the save Form. why? how i can improve speed?

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect this slot to a QPushButton:

```
void MainWindow::openFD(){
   QTime myopentime=QTime::currentTime();
   for (int i=0;i<1000000;i++) ;//comment out this line for the real test
   QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,QString(),QString(myopentime.toString("m.s.zzz")+" "+QTime::currentTime().toString("m.s.zzz"))
                                                  ,tr("*.csv") );
}
```

Then try to run it with and without the count part.

You will see, that the count part adds some ms... without it there is not even ms (mili-second) of difference in the time shown in filename place.

So, you have to search somewhere else in your code or give us a better example.

PS:
1) You will need :

```
#include <QTime>
```

2) The line that counting is there to show you that my method works (since you will see some difference when uncomment)

**Result and Answer:** The problem is not on QFileDialog if this test will not give you differences but somewhere else in your code or possibly in the Window manager of your OS.

Comment: Solved. Problem is only in debug mode.

Comment: @javad you can post an answer yourself or accept mine if you think it helped you... It is good for the forums we use not to have ananswered posts...